# Is the size of the conjugacy class of a given element in a compact Lie group always finite?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $g\in G$ be any given element in it. Consider the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$, denoted by $[g]=\{hgh^{-1}:h\in G\}$. Our question is that:

Could you find a $g_0\in G$ such that the size of $[g_0]$, denoted by $|[g_0]|$, is infinite?

Moreover, how about the same question for compact simple Lie groups.

Comment: Have you looked at any examples at all? Almost every conjugacy class of $SU(2)$ is infinite.

Comment: Thx....I realize I have asked a stupid question..._(:з」∠)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This size is almost always infinite.  The group $G$ acts on the conjugacy class by conjugation and this is isomorphic to the coset action $G/C_G(g)$.  If the conjugacy class is finite, then $C_G(g)$ is an open subgroup, which means it must be a union of connected components.  So, for example, if $G$ is connected, then every element with finite conjugacy class is central.  If $G$ is simple, then there are only finitely many such elements.

Consider a case like $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$; the conjugacy classes are elements with the same Jordan normal form.  There are only finitely many elements with a given Jordan normal form if it's a scalar matrix $\lambda I$.

Comment: Thx, you are right. But the example $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is not compact. As mentioned by Yuan above, there are so many examples. I admit that it is a stupid question.

Comment: You can take $U(n)$ instead, which is even a little easier to understand since everything is diagonalizable.

Comment: For a geometric example, the conjugacy class of a nontrivial rotation $R$ in ${\rm SO}(3)$ by an angle of $\theta$ is the set of all rotations around axes by an angle of $\theta$. (Indeed, if $R$ rotates around the oriented axis $\ell$ by $\theta$, then $SRS^{-1}$ rotates around the oriented axis $S\ell$ by angle $\theta$, and ${\rm SO}(3)$ acts transitively on oriented axes.)